# Google Slides: how to avoid image compression with loss of quality?

Tags: google-slides

Most images I insert in my presentations are not modified or compressed by Google Slides.

But some are compressed with loss of quality, like this one:

[image: Slide with compressed image:]
**I can't find the reason why these images specifically are compressed (file format, image passing a certain thresold of size, dimensions... ?).**

This is cumbersome as the images are compressed too much, to the point where the text on the screenshot is not visible anymore...

**Do you have any idea how to avoid this ?**

Comment: Sacha - did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @BobCavezza I found a workaround - posted in an answer

Comment: Google tends to bury images that are low res so that you can't see the individual pixels.

Answer (score 3):

When I added images that were larger (dimensions-wise) than the slide size, Google Slides scaled the image to fit on the slide and downsampled the image accordingly. If I scaled the image to be larger (closer to its original size) and cropped it in Google Slides, then it came out pixelated.

I was able to avoid this by first cropping the image in another program, then uploading the cropped image to Google Slides

Comment: For me it's the exact opposite: The original image is smaller, and Google Slides blows it up to a larger size, about 1.3 times the original size, for no obvious reason whatsoever. The fact that the image formatting options always express size in inches makes me think that they have a bug, determining an incorrect DPI. Would love for a pixel size option where we can at least fix it manually. This bug is as old as Slides... crazy they still have not fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems images are sharper if the slide page size is 2 or 4 times larger. The slide page size can be customized in File-> Page setup -> custom -> 40x23.2 inches. [image: page setup]

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried up to 8x page size and still got downsampling on my test image in the export PDF.